# Where can I find free content hosting?

Tags: javascript, hosting, cdn, content-delivery-network

Is there any free hosting for Javascript? Recently google has been hosting jQuery,etc... and Yahoo hosts it's YUI, which is great, but it'd be even better if there was a service that could host user scripts and things like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: While the question could probably be reworded, this is a helpful question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356231/cannot-get-flowtype-js-to-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn Google AppEngine in to your own CDN.  Which will definitely give you the effect you are looking for.

http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/06/turn-google-app-engine-into-a-content-delivery-network-cdn/

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed, I'd looked into Google Apps, but I failed to see it as CDN for scripts and other static content. Kudos

Answer (score 3):

i found another great free javascript file hosting. www.yourjavascript.com
they have a nice feature to access the file for specific domains.

Comment: the domain feature is a nice feature :)