# Cannot get FlowType.js to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, typography

I've inserted the following right before the `</body>` tag and the type isn't changing at all.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

https://github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS

http://jsfiddle.net/tawshmcd/gLJxE/

--

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://raw.github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS/master/flowtype.js"></script>

<script>
    $('body').flowtype({
     minimum   : 500,
     maximum   : 1200,
     minFont   : 12,
     maxFont   : 40,
     fontRatio : 30,
     lineRatio : 1.45
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have jquery.js linked? Do you have any error in console?

Comment: FYI: I've just put the following two lines in front of your code: `<script src='jquery.js'></script>`
`<script src='flowtype.js'></script>` and add some text in the body section. Work's ok with latest Chrome and FF.

Comment: Yes, .js is linked, see above.

Comment: Can you go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and create a sample that illustrates the problem, then update your question with the link?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer below, the problem is: "https://raw.github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS/master/flowtype.js" won't work. Github discourages directly linking to source code hosted on their site, by not setting the mimetype properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Don't src from raw.github.com**.

The problem is that you're sourcing the flowtype.js file from github raw. Github raw returns javascript as type plaintext (to discourage sourcing from github raw).

Since the file has the wrong mimetype, the webbrowser won't execute it as javascript.

To fix the problem you will need to find a proper host for the file. You can host it yourself via a local webserver, or find a free CDN account to put the file up.

Edit to add:

With your JS Fiddle, if you open the Javascript console, you'll see the following error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://raw.github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS/master/flowtype.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.